# 'rails generate model' fails to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I inherited a Rails application and am having quite a difficult time generating a model. Running 'rails generate model Account' pauses for a moment, but then returns me to the command prompt without the output I would normally expect from a successful operation.

Environment info:

-Rails 4.2.5

-Ruby 2.3.0p, loaded via RVM

I've spent hours trying to debug this myself and have found a few interesting things:

1.) Generating a controller works as expected, only models seem broken

2.) If I create a new Rails project I can generate models as expected

3.) I've verified that spring is not running, using "spring stop"

4.) A similar problem is mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389603/rails-generate-model-returns-nothing) by a user with my same environment. I verified I'm in the proper dir, and also tried running "bundle update" as suggested by a user, but that didn't resolve the problem.

A few other resources allude to this being a problem with RVM, but rolling back to older versions of Ruby haven't made a difference.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe an issue with bin/rails?  What's your output from `which rails`?

Comment: What if you try by deleting your `Gemfile.lock`, and then `bundle` again. I suggest that, just because `bundle update` works for someone else. Maybe it worth a try.

Comment: @SomeGuy output is `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rails`

Comment: Have you tried using `bundle exec rails generate ...`?

Comment: @Bartosz didn't work either

Comment: @Horacio Not sure this is related, but doing that gives me `Please require the stackprof gem falling back to fast_stack
/Users/fslone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/backports-3.6.8/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in require: cannot load such file -- fast_stack (LoadError)`

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help, painfully new to Rails so I'm especially baffled why something so simple is failing for me.

Comment: Could you paste the console output?

Comment: @pedrozath not a whole lot of information there 


`3.2 >>> rails generate model Test`


`Please require the stackprof gem falling back to fast_stack`


`3.2 >>>`

Comment: are you using [flamegraph](https://github.com/SamSaffron/flamegraph) ??

Comment: @AmolUdage I am indeed. I fixed my problem with not being able to generate models but if you know how to squash that stackprof message related to flamegraph I would be eternally grateful

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

1. `bundle config --delete bin`
2. `rake rails:update:bin`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I assume the intent of this was to re-install bin/rails but the command returns that the files are identical

Answer (score 0):

Was able to reach out to one of the previous developers and learned that I'm dealing with JSONClient models and that's why it isn't working for me. D'oh!